# List all checked-out files in PlasticSCM?

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

I know I left some files checked out in another non-local workspace, but I want to find them. How can I find the list of all files that are currently checked out? Via command-line or the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two option to see which files are checked out.

In the GUI.
Select 'Pending Changes' or 'Workspace Explorer' from the 'Main Actions' menu.
Files that are checked out will be have a 'Checked-out' status.

[Pending Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4kXA.jpg)

[Workspace Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWaBe.jpg)